# Send proper api call using RestSharp to getresponse.com api

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a contact email address to a existing campaign list named- "liakat". But I am getting a response from getresponse.com saying httpStatus 400, which you can check on the attached pitures. I have added a temporary api key, so you can test it yourself too. I am following [this document](http://apidocs.getresponse.com/v3/case-study/adding-contacts) from getresponse.com. Anyone who can fix this issue?

[image: Pic]

Controller:

```
string email = "test@gmail.com";

            // Test Campaign name - "pikaa"
            // "pikaa" named campaign ID->ee104303
            // our api key->  948dsdfsdfs1a017a07f3c6

            var client = new RestClient("https://api.getresponse.com/v3/contacts");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;





            var root = new RootObject();

            root.campaign = new Campaign();

            root.name = "Mr Men";
            root.email = "test@gmail.com";
            root.campaign.campaignId = "IDss6604303";


            var jsBody = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(root);

            request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", "api-key 948sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs6");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "email=" + email + "&campaign=ID85104303", ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Model:

```
public class Campaign
        {
            public string campaignId { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public Campaign campaign { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "connection" between the Request `request` and the JSON Object `jsBody` (or `root`). What you're sending is a **query string**.
Something like

> email=test@gmail.com&campaign=ID85104303

This is defined by the line:

```
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "email=" + email + "&campaign=ID85104303", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

If you want to send your JSON, you need to change the line to:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I can't tell if this will already work, but so you're at least sending the right body and you should get a successful response or at least a better error message.